# Dependency and chaining of actions in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a card game score management app with React, where I need to add & remove players but also associate them to different tables (a table contains 4 players).

The thing is, I'm just getting started with Redux and I'm having trouble modelling my store and handling dependent actions.

I thought I should use [Redux's subscribe method](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) to listen for players changes and create/associate them to tables accordingly, but I'm not sure it's the correct way to do handle this sort of dependency.

Also, I'm struggling with the players/tables association: should I have an array of players and an array of tables and then associate a player to a table ID or associate players' IDs to a table?

Comment: Use [React Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to connect your store to your components. Manually calling `subscribe` on the store is very rare outside of library code, in my experience.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using React Redux. Do you think I can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecyle method to update my tables when players are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach for organizing relational data in a Redux store is to "normalize" the state.  See the [Redux FAQ on relational data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data) and the [Structuring Reducers - Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) docs page.

And yes, per @Joe Clay's comment, you should generally not call `store.subscribe` yourself, but rather use the React-Redux `connect` function to handle store subscriptions for your components.

Comment: The part on normalizing the state shape for relational data really helped, I went with the recommended structure of using `byId` and `allIds`, which pretty much solved all my relational concerns.